# Aberration of light

Tags: taylor-expansion

[See the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwVhK.png)

I'm trying to derive unnumbered formula between 5.6 and 5.7 but cannot actually get how and what to expand. Could you pls write it in details. Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Please try LaTeX everything on this website. Also, please double check (5.6) is typoless, as I think clearly there is a type on sin (i.e. one of them should contain a ‘)

Answer (score 0):

As @Rescy_ has already pointed out, there is a typo in the equation on left. Besides, it is always a good habit to use MathJax tools as described at [MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your problem statement.

In this answer we use the typo-removed equation,
$$\sin\left(\theta\right)=\dfrac{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{V^2}{c^2}}}{1+\dfrac{V}{c}\cos\left(\theta’\right)}\sin\left(\theta’\right).$$

We know that $V\lt\lt c$. Therefore, we have $\dfrac{V^2}{c^2}\lt\lt 1$ and we can write,
$$\sin\left(\theta\right)=\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{V}{c}\cos\left(\theta’\right)}\sin\left(\theta’\right).$$

Using this equation, we obtain an expression for $\sin\left(\theta\right)- \sin\left(\theta’\right)$ as shown below.

$$\sin\left(\theta\right)- \sin\left(\theta’\right)= \dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{V}{c}\cos\left(\theta’\right)}\sin\left(\theta’\right)- \sin\left(\theta’\right)=\left(\dfrac{1-1-\dfrac{V}{c}\cos\left(\theta’\right)}{1+\dfrac{V}{c}\cos\left(\theta’\right)}\right)\sin\left(\theta’\right)$$

$$\sin\left(\theta\right)- \sin\left(\theta’\right)=-\left(\dfrac{\dfrac{V}{c}\cos\left(\theta’\right)}{1+\dfrac{V}{c}\cos\left(\theta’\right)}\right)\sin\left(\theta’\right)\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\space$$

Since $\dfrac{V}{c}\cos\left(\theta’\right)\lt\lt 1$, we have,
$$\sin\left(\theta\right)- \sin\left(\theta’\right)=- \dfrac{V}{c}\cos\left(\theta’\right)\sin\left(\theta’\right).$$